# Cannot POST (node/express), what am I missing?

Tags: node.js, express, post

I'm trying to use a simple POST request with Node using Express and instead am getting cannot POST with a 404. In the end I want to use ajax so it POSTs without refreshing the page in the browser, but first I need to get it running like this and I can't figure out what I've gotten wrong.

public/form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input name="firstName">
    <input name="lastName">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//server running?
  app.listen(3000,() => {
    console.log('Started on PORT 3000');
  })

//Serve the web page directory
app.use(express.static('./public'))
//Return form fields
app.post('form.html', (req, res) => {
    console.log("First name: " + req.body.firstName)
    console.log("Last name: " + req.body.lastName)
res.end()
})
```

Comment: inside `action` you should provide the route you want to request to, this should match with the route inside your server route.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post("/api", (req, res) => {
    console.log("First name: " + req.body.firstName);
    console.log("Last name: " + req.body.lastName);
    res.end();
});
```

Here you have to make POST request to `/api`

```
<form method="POST" action="/api">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out and will share in case others are looking for the same thing. The other responses are correct, but I was looking to POST without changing the URL. This doesn't look to be possible because I always get cannot POST and a 404 if I point to the existing page (either leaving action empty or using "#").

However, when you use AJAX, you still point to a new URL with the form action attribute and in your node app, but your AJAX code will keep the URL on the same page (the page doesn't refresh).